# Display multiply markers in the map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

so i works in a geolocation project(**asp.net MVC4**), i have many positions in my database and i want to show it in my map, my problem that the script just show the first position, this is my script:

```
var checkpoints = [];
function setMarkers(map, locations) {

for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++)
{
    var place = locations;
    for (var i = 0; i < place.length; i++)
    {
        var points = new google.maps.LatLng(place[i][1], place[i][2]); 
        checkpoints.push(points);
    }

    var check = checkpoints[0];
    var index = 0;
    for (var j = 0; j < checkpoints.length; j++)
    {
            check = checkpoints[j];
            index = j;
            var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(place[index][1], place[index][2]);    

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker
                (
                    {
                        position: myLatLng,
                        map: map,
                        title: place[index][0],
                        zIndex: place[index][3]
                    }
                );
    }
}
return marker;
}
```

so please if someone have any solution or idea i will be very appreciate.

Thanks everyone @david @Beetroot-Beetroot @razzak my script works fine now, this is my new script :

```
var checkpoints = [];
function setMarkers(map, locations) {

for (var i in locations) {
    var points = new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]);
    checkpoints.push(points);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: points,
        title: locations[i][0],
        zindex: locations[i][4]
    });
}
}
```

**Update :**
my script works fine but i have a small problem in my event, when i dblclick on a marker it should show his title but it just show me the title of the last marker :

```
var checkpoints = [];
function setMarkers(map, locations) {

for (var i in locations) {
    var points = new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]);
    checkpoints.push(points);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: points,
        title: locations[i][0],
        zindex: locations[i][4],
    });
    //this is my event
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dblclick', function () {
        alert("I am marker " + marker.title);
    });
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have simplified your code

```
function setMarkers(locations) {
    for(var i in locations) {
    var points = new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1].lat,locations[i][2].lng);
    checkpoints.push(points);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
     map:map,
     position: points,
     icon: 'myicon.png',//
     title: locations[i][0],
     zindex: locations[i][4]
    }); 

   } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you again @david it works but u should update the following lines :var points = new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]);                                                            and :        title: locations[i][0],
            zindex: locations[i][4]

Comment: i have just a small problem in my event,it show me the same title:                                        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dblclick', function () {
        alert("I am marker " + marker.title);
    });

Answer (score 0):

Mohammadov, you are making it more complicated than it needs to be.

Try this :

```
function setMarkers(map, locations) {
    for(var i=0; i<locations.length; i++) {
        var loc = locations[i];
        loc[4] = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(loc[1], loc[2]),
            map: map,
            title: loc[0],
            zIndex: loc[3]
        });
    }
}
```

The map should then show the markers, and each member of the `locations` array should be augmented with a reference to its marker, as element [4].

Answer (score 0):

the two loops inside the main loop are causing problems, they are unnecessary and can be avoided. also return marker at the end of the loop will return only the last one, you can remove it as well:

```
var checkpoints = [];

function setMarkers(map, locations) {    
for (var i=0; i<locations.length; i++)
{
    var place    = locations[i],
        myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(place[1], place[2]),   
        marker = new google.maps.Marker
                (
                    {
                        position: myLatLng,
                        map: map,
                        title: place[0],
                        zIndex: place[3]
                    }
                );
    checkpoints.push({"point": myLatLng, "marker": marker}); 
}
}
```

The checkpoints now should have an array of `LatLng` and `marker` of each place.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arcm111/mMZyH/)

Comment: Thanks @razzak but it still not working the loop is still loop 1 time

Comment: NB: when i close the loop here :                                    for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++)
    {
        var place = locations[i];
        myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(place[1], place[2]);   alert(place);
    }

Comment: you should declare `checkpoints` variable outside `initialize()` function and `setMarkers()` inside it, call `setMarkers()` at the end of `initialize()` function. see this demo for more info http://jsfiddle.net/arcm111/mMZyH/